# Javascript: Pull csv data from web and store in array

Tags: javascript, csv, web, fetch

I am trying to develop a javascript that pulls csv data from an external website and store it in an array. The reason why I am need this to be in javascript is that I am using a chrome extension called Shortkeys that can execute javascript code. I want the script to get (csv) data from an API (url), look through the csv data and generate a string based on the csv data. So far I've been trying with the fetch function, but Im new to javascript. So far I've got, but I dont really know what Im doing:

```
const url = 'https://myAPIurl.com';

fetch(url)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(contents => console.log(contents))
```

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Hello Peter, could you use http://jsfiddle.net to make an example of your code with a real api? That way I can help you better

Comment: Thanks, Alejandro.
http://jsfiddle.net/8oa91tk3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of setting every value of every row in a collection, but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openmundi/world.csv/master/countries(204)_olympics.csv')
  .then(response => response.text()).then(text => { 
     const lines = text.split('\n')
     const columns = lines.map((line) => line.split(','))
     console.log(columns)
  })
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is definitely in the direction I'm aiming to go. How would one go about to store the data in an array followed by looping through each line?

Comment: Your code works, but when I try with my own url I get the error 
  _Access to fetch at 'https://myAPI...' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled._

Comment: .map is looping though each line, and .split is returning an array for each line, that's why as a result, you can see an array containing each line. You can do whatever you like inside the .map function

Comment: Regarding CORS, you can modify the fetch to work with cors this way `fetch('URL', { .mode: 'cors' })`, but you will also need to return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: */*` from the server and I'm not sure if you have got control over the server code.

Comment: Have a look at this to understand it better https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks for info. Could using `GET` HTTP request be a better solution then?

Comment: fetch is `GET` by default, so it will be the same I'm afraid.